# Using name keys in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, labeling, internationalization

When contributing to OpenStreetMap one can set a general ("default") `name` as well as further language specific names (e.g. `name:de`).

**Example:**

```
name Joe's Guesthouse
name:en Joe's Guesthouse
name:de Joe's Gasthof
```

as well as

```
int_name Joe's Guesthouse
```

Is it mandatory to set the general `name` key, or can I avoid using the `name` key, and just use the language specific `name:xx` keys instead?

For foreign speakers, one could only set the `int_name` instead of `name:en`.

I am confused about the the explanation on [key:name description](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` key always refers to the name of the object in the *local* language. You should always set `name` if the object has a name. Just setting the language specific `name:xx` key doesn't make much sense (except if you don't know the local name but just the foreign name).

This type of question is better asked at https://help.openstreetmap.org/.